# Installing PyQt4 in Mac OS X and Maya

Tags: macos, installation, pyqt4, macports, maya

I am trying to run PyQt4 in Maya 2014 and I keep getting the error that no modules was found etc.

I am a Mac user on OS X 10.7.5 and I have tried running the installation following this [link](http://www.pythonschool.net/mac_pyqt/) as my guide. 
Unfortunately though I am able to install everything as stated, but as I am unable to get the IDLE.app from MacPorts, thus I tried checking whether the PyQt4 is installed either by terminal or through Maya itself where I typed in `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`

However both methods still state the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

Can anyone help me through? Or do I still need to install something else just for Maya-usage?
It would seems that the python package in my machine is Python 2.7.1 as depicted from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

For 2014+ you may want to use [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), which comes with your Maya and won't need separate installation.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Well.. I have been using PyQt4 and I am just in fear that changing to PySide will mess up my bearings etc. Noob qns here - but are PySide any different from PyQt? Additionally any ideas if the stuff I have installed can be uninstalled?

Comment: They are both wrappers around the C++ (i think it's C++) core of QT. They are quite similar, since most of the names and constructs are coming straight from QT anyway.

http://nathanhorne.com/?p=451
http://forums.thefoundry.co.uk/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=8401&sid=faa6547f12db5d552eb6432718064b2f

I don't have any experience with the installation on Macs, although it sounds like the sort of thing I have run into with older versions of PyQT -- which is why I abandoned it.

Comment: Is it impossible to use pyqt4 on osx via macports?